# Weird LLDB error in Xcode 4.5: Internal error [IRForTarget]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

When putting breakpoint in some files, for example: Just newly created ViewController and putting breakpoint on `viewDidLoad` method I get strange LLDB error

```
Internal error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't rewrite external variable _ZZ53
[EPGViewController($__lldb_category) $__lldb_expr:]E19$__lldb_expr_result
```

I tried googling for this error - can't find anything useful. Cleaning cache, restarting doesn't help.

Once more - this error I get not on all files. And I can't figure out why.
Thx for any help or tips!

Also, when I try to `po` some variable I get

```
(lldb) po self.title
error: Couldn't materialize struct: Structure hasn't been laid out yet
Internal error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't rewrite external variable _ZZ58-
[EventsEPGViewController($__lldb_category) $__lldb_expr:]E19$__lldb_expr_result
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error as well and spent a lot of time debugging it fruitlessly.  It seems to be related to the breakpoint itself: I noticed that if I deactivated the breakpoint the error doesn't appear.

You might be able to just move the breakpoint to another line to suppress. This isn't the first clang bug I've run into, on XCode 4.3 'po' wouldn't even output variables reliably.

Comment: changing a line doesn't help (

Answer (score 0):

Change your designated debugger for that project from lldb to gdb and you're good.